# Is it okay to have a NULL value for datetime data type in database?

Tags: sql-server, database, datetime, null

I have this table Equipment Activity Table

```
CREATE TABLE EqpActivityTBL
(
    EqpAct_ID              INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    EqpAct_BorrowDateTime  DATETIME,
    EqpAct_ReturnDateTime  DATETIME,
    EqpAct_Room            VARCHAR(50),
    SysUser_ID             INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SysUserTBL,
    DeptMember_ID          INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DeptMemberTBL,
    Eqp_ID                 INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EqpTBL,
    EqpAct_Status          VARCHAR(50)
)
```

As you can see, I have an EqpAct_ReturnDate column. It will have a value of the date once an equipment is returned. But if it wasn't returned or maybe destroyed or perhaps something bad happened to it(sending it to dark hole perhaps) , can I insert a NULL value in that column? It has a datetime data type, anyways. I'm trying to show here that something has failed to return. I'm trying my best to avoid NULL value on the other data types.

Bottomline is: Is it fine to have a NULL value on datetime?

Thanks in advance

Comment: surely you can have null value and even on INT unless you define NOT NULL during table description

Comment: Yes.If you have a nullable datetime column, then its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works fine. A null value represents a missing value better than using some magic date value.

There may be a slightly lower perfomance using a field that can handle null, so you should disallow it for the fields that shouldn't ever be null.

Comment: I do not buy disallow null for "may be a slightly performance" - okay, more [hypothetical] work is more work, but this should not even be considered as a primary consideration! If there should/can be a NULL, then it should be nullable. Otherwise, it should not be nullable.

Comment: @pst: Yes, the main consideration should of course be to help keeping the data consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to have null value, but it would add overhead in code (for checking null)...Alternatively, you can keep a default value like 01-01-1900.

Comment: Using magic values is generally considered bad practice, especially if you need to have the value in more than one place in the code, and it's not much difference in overhead between checking for null and checking for a magic value.

Comment: @Guffa Agree that there is not much difference in checking null and checking a value...but it will add complexity in typecasting...Before casting, u need to check the value...in case its DBNull, you need to assign default value (DateTime.Min) to your variable...while in this case, you can just cast the value in DateTime n use it.No need to check if null and then assign default value in case of null.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes, null can be allowed in the datetime format of yours

It is just that you need to write some extra code will checking null (to avoid null reference errors). Instead you can leave it to default like it will take some thing like 19 : 00 : 00 (or anything else) so that you know that it is the deault value. Here no parsing will be required.

Answer (score 0):

I ask:
DATETIME is an 8 byte datatype.  You can make that column nullable, but it is a fixed-width data type.  Isn't it?
The NULL values will still take up 8 bytes.